# PHP Format colour of table?

Tags: php, sql, format

I have a table coded a little like below:

```
echo "<table class='lt show'>
      <tr class='h'>
      <td class='ltid' title='Position'>#</td>
      <td class='ltn' title='Name'>Name</td>";

$i = 0;

while ($i < $num){
    $pos = $i + 1;

    $name = mysql_result($result, $i, "name");

    $bgcolor = 'bgcolor="'.$color.'"';

    if ($pos <=  19) $color = "#FFF";

    echo "<tr $bgcolor class='even'><td class='ltid'>$pos</td>
          <td class='ltn'><a href='teams.php?id=$id'>$name</td>";
```

This returns a table of 20 rows each containing different positions and names.
How can I make the bottom two rows / the 20 be red to indicate they're at the bottom of the table?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you seem to be missing a closing bracket for the while loop - not sure if that's just a copy and paste error.

Answer (score 1):

Note MySQL functions have been  depreceated in favour of PDO.

Saying that, this is how you do it

```
$num= mysql_num_rows ($result);
while ($i < $num){
$pos = $i + 1;

$name = mysql_result($result, $i, "name");

$bgcolor = 'bgcolor="'.$color.'"';

if ($pos <  $result-2) $color = "#FFF";

echo "<tr $bgcolor class='even'><td class='ltid'>$pos</td>
      <td class='ltn'><a href='teams.php?id=$id'>$name</td>";
}
```

Comment: Note: bgcolor is **not** a valid attribute according to the HTML5 specs and was deprecated in HTML4. CSS classes should be used instead.

Comment: Knew that. So has border, cellpadding and cellspacing. But its mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mysql_num_rows() function to compute the number of rows in your result set, then minus two from the total to determine the loop index to set the colour to red:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php
```

Note these functions are deprecated though in favour of mysqli and PDO. Not so sure if that concerns you or not.

Or you could do an SQL count directly:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Table;
```

Which would return you a set count, the choice is yours - without an awareness of the total numer of rows being iterated, there is no way of determining which point to set the row colour.